# What type of formal notation is being used here to represent functional algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, functional-programming, notation

Interested in learning more about algorithm design in functional programming, I picked up Andrew Bird's [Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521513383).  I have experience with a number of programming languages, but my only experience with functional programming is in Scala.  I understood that I would have to pick-up Standard ML and Haskell from the description of the book, but when I started reading the first section, I wasn't familiar with some of the operators being used.

Here are some examples of function definitions from the first chapter of the book (free to preview on Amazon):

---

[image: weird syntax]

I have seen "^" and "v" used to represent "and" and "or," but some of the other syntax (like `False (0,n)`) still throws me off.

[image: more weird syntax]

In this one, I'm not sure what the `accumArray(+)...` is referring to.  I'm thinking it's like a fold method using addition, but I don't understand the rest of the line.

[image: kinda weird]

Here, the author has done a good job of describing that \\ is [set difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_difference#Relative_complement) and the two vertical lines crossed with a horizontal one is [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).  However, I've never seen anything like that union symbol before.

---

I don't want to know what each of these examples means as much as I want to know **what library of formal representation is Bird using to represent these algorithms**, and also, if a specific programming language (Haskell/SML?) syntax is being used as well in conjunction with these special symbols.

Comment: What exactly about `False (0, n)` for example throws you off?

Comment: By the way, `False (0, n)` is not a subexpression. `False` and `(0, n)` are two values, given as arguments to `accumArray`.

Comment: @phant0m coming from my programming experience, it looked like there was a method called `False` that was taking two parameters: 0 and n.  But C. A. McCann cleared up the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidKaczynski: I suspected that was some of the confusion. Haskell functions take one argument at a time and function application is written as juxtaposition. Here, `accumArray` is being applied to four arguments--a "logical or" function, the boolean value `False`, a 2-tuple (pair) of `Int`s that appear to be array bounds, and a list of `(Int, Bool)` pairs filtered so the `Int`s are valid array indices (the whole second line). The `where` clause just defines `n` as the length of the input list within the scope of the function body.

Comment: @DavidKaczynski: Also, you are correct in thinking this is a sort of fold. I assume it's using [this `accumArray` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/0.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Array.html#v:accumArray), which the documentation describes pretty clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language is pretty-printed Haskell.

In regular source code, it would look like this:

```
checklist :: [Int] -> Array Int Bool
checklist xs = accumArray (||) False (0, n)
               (zip (filter (<= n) xs) (repeat True))
               where n = length xs

countlist :: [Int] -> Array Int Int
countlist xs = accumArray (+) 0 (0, n) (zip xs (repeat 1))

(as ++ bs) \\ cs = (as \\ cs) ++ (bs \\ cs) -- Not actual code
as \\ (bs ++ cs) = (as \\ bs) \\ cs
(as \\ bs) \\ cs = (as \\ cs) \\ bs
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because the ASCII translation put it in terms that I better understand.  Well, time for me to start learning Haskell.  Cheers!

Comment: @DavidKaczynski No problem, note that I just fixed a mistake: It needs to be `(||)`, not `(or)` which is the same as `or` which is wrong ;)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the book but the snapshot is definitely Haskell. Most texts that contain Haskell code use some kind of pretty printer, most likely [lhs2TeX](http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/). It assigns more type-setting-friendly symbols to many standard Haskell infix operations such as `++` or `<=`.

I suggest you to use browse Haskell's [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html) module, which contains functions available to all Haskell programs by default. Or you can search for a particular function using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Comment: The biggest giveaway is the use of `::` for type annotations. That's unique to Haskell and languages derived from it that borrow its syntax in full.